# I would like to add a date column to my data frame. The date column needs to populate automatically for the full length of the column

Tags: r, cbind

I would like to add a date column to a data frame. The date column needs to populate automatically for the full length of the column. See example below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTjbA.png)

Data frame:

```
df = structure(list(Name = c("Joe", "Sanj", "Rob"), 
                    Col1 = c(20, 60, 40), 
                    Col2 = c(100, 233, 500)),  
               row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
               class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What's the value you want to have?

Comment: any date is ok, just repeated.  For example, 12/8/2020

Comment: `transform(df, Date = Sys.Date())` ?

Comment: GREAT, THANK YOU MAESTRO!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Sys.Date()` (todays date) as a new column.

```
df$Date <- Sys.Date()

# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Name   Col1  Col2 Date      
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
#1 Joe      20   100 2020-08-12
#2 Sanj     60   233 2020-08-12
#3 Rob      40   500 2020-08-12
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is by doing the following:

```
df$date <- as.Date("2020-08-12")
```

This assigns the data value "2020-08-12" to a new column in **df** called **date**. When assigning a length 1 vector to a new column of a dataframe, R will recycle to the same length as the columns in your dataframe (3 in this case). We wrap your date ("2020-08-21") in *as.Date()* so the column class is "date". If we do not do this, the class will be "character".